# What is probability that a team reaches final if we know the probabilities of all opponents in the semi-final?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Our Discrete Math professor asked us a question as the Euros are going on.

Given the following info, what is the probability that Portugal will make it to the final?
Win Probabilities in quarter finals:
Portugal vs Poland - Portugal 1
Wales vs Belgium - Belgium 0.7

Win probabilities in semi finals
Portugal vs Belgium - Portugal 0.5
Portugal vs Wales - Portugal 0.75

Here is what my thought process is:
I drew a probability tree:

```
                     Belgium  Belgium = 0.35
                0.50 /
        Belgium
    0.7 /       0.50 \
                     Portugal  
QF                            Portugal = 0.35 + 0.225 = 0.575
                     Portugal
    0.3 \       0.75 /
        Wales   
                0.25 \
                     Wales  Wales = 0.075
```

Is this the correct way of solving the problem?

Thanks

Comment: It is indeed $0.575$.

Comment: My Polish friends wish to argue about some of the assumptions.

Comment: Its an axiom :P